# How to rearrange code with overridden methods at the top in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, code-formatting

In the `Preferences > Code Style > Arrangement`- tab, I have to manually enter matching rules for specific method names if I want to arrange them to be at the top.

For example, I have an activity where I want the lifecycle- and other overridden methods to be at the top:

```
public final class MyActivity extends Activity {
    // Fields

    @Override
    public final void onCreate(...) { ... }
    ...

    // Other methods
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7):

In Android Studio 3.0 under `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Arrangement Tab` you can add a rule to match **overridden** and place it after the rules for fields and constructors but before the rules for methods.

You can then perform `Code > Rearrange Code` and it should arrange your code appropriately

[image: Arrangement Screenshot]